# Blender 2.8 Beta: OpenGL 3.3 Error?

Tags: drivers, error, opengl

Before I start, YES, I have done my own research - I know how annoying a repeat question is. Yet each answer is so specific to others...

When I tried the beta 2.8 64 bit, it says "Blender requires a driver with at least OpenGL 3.3 support. The program will now close."

[image]

The question: I know that it is true that 2.8 requires OpenGL 3.3. But does my PC not have it, doesn't support it, or do I have it and blender won't detect it? I'm not sure what info to include or what to look for, so here's my PC's specs:

Windows 10 (64 bit)
Core -        Intel Core i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
RAM -         8GB (7.89GB usable)
System type - 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Graphics properties:

[image]

Comment: What is your Graphics Card?

Comment: "*Yet each answer is so specific to others*" That is a good sign that these kinds of questions are not a good fit for this site

Comment: @Sazerac Is this it? (see my edit). I can't get a clear answer online if it supports OpenGL3.3 or not.

Comment: I had this exact same problem and this video fixed it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TsY_-PvB13g

Comment: @AbrahamBrookes I know that this is an old comment but this method actually worked for me today thanks! Only issue is that the GUI (not rendering) in just the default scene is horribly slow, probably 5 FPS. CPU is running max. Oh well, probably time to dump my integrated graphics already :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update your graphics card drivers, if Blender works, your graphics card supports required OpenGL version if not, it doesn't.

In this particular case a quick Google search reveals that Intel HD Graphics 2000 Adapter supports only OpenGL 3.1. This means the graphics card will not be suitable for running Blender 2.80.

The good news is that pretty much any new graphics card will most likely support required OpenGL version and you will not struggle finding a wide choice of suitable graphics cards in a very wide variety of prices. Even cheap graphics cards are capable of running Blender 2.80. However, if you are planing to use EEVEE, you will probably want a more expensive one.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the Intel Graphics chips don't work with OpenGL 3.3. I've tried it on multiple devices, each with the latest driver version, and it just won't work. If you can, try to get a GPU like an NVIDIA or AMD, staying away from Intel or other integrated GPUs. I'm running 2.8 on an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 525M (Crappy and old, but superior to integrated graphics) which you could pick up for pretty cheap. It is a mobile GPU, so be careful.

Comment: You can of course use integrated graphics from AMD and NVIDIA, as long as they support OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: IF you can find them. Does NVIDIA still make integrated graphics chips?