# Blender won't open on windows 10 32 bit

Tags: opengl

this week I installed windows 10 32 bits on my old laptop because i was bored of linux but I could not install windows 10 64 bits for some reason. I installed blender but I got this message

```
Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Warning! OpenGL core profile not available.
Warning! Ignoring untested OpenGL context profile mask bits.Win32 Error# (3221692565): The specified OpenGL version and feature set are either invalid or not supported.
```

I tried to update IntelHD driver but the drivers are up to date. Blender was working fine on linux Ubuntu 64 bits and now it won't open.

Could someone help me please ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/48onR.jpg

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Blender 2.8 Beta: OpenGL 3.3 Error?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/137257/blender-2-8-beta-opengl-3-3-error)

Comment: Your hardware does not support OpenGL 3.3 which is required to run Blender 2.8. The minimum requirements are documented here: https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: Normaly it should work because I have the minimum requirements, I have 4GB of ram, i5 M520 CPU (2.4Ghz),1280x800 screen and 1.6GB of ram for my GPU, and blender 2.8 was working fine on linux.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/D640nGj

Comment: Unfortunately no you don't, your integrated GPU doesn't fulfill the minimum requirements. Haswell or later is required. It may have worked on Linux because they offered a driver which allowed OpenGL 3.3 to run. The hardware is still unsupported though.

Comment: Intel doesn't even provide a driver update for Windows 10, only for 7 and Vista. See: https://downloadcenter.intel.com/en/product/47341/intel-core-i5-520m-processor-3m-cache-2-40-ghz As unfortunate as it is, maybe it's time for a hardware upgrade if you want to use Blender 2.8.

Comment: your gpu supported opengl 3.3 well for blender 2.8 because in linux UNIX you can emulate opengl in software and hardware, in windows there is no possibility to emulate opengl in software, I recommend you not leave in the comments of doubtful origin and lacking of foundations that support this opinion, consult an expert in linux forums to be clearer because you can use 2.8 in linux and not in windows, I will try to compile a 2.8 with support for open gl 3.0 but I doubt that it works well for what I have been reading from the source code

Comment: It should be mentioned that your card seems to be no longer support an update of openGL 3.3 on windows but in Linux if it can work, it all depends on the distribution you use